# VBA How to create a data validation loop with single value copy/paste and offset

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro that loops through a data validation list I have located in cell C8 on the sheet named Gym Weekly Template. For each value in the data validation list (the list is made up of data from Range A6:A45 from sheet "Testing Data"), I have a vlookup value that generates in cell **W73** of the same sheet.

I want to paste each value from cell **W73** to a new worksheet named Gym Load Monitoring starting at cell **B2** and down the **B** column, ending the macro once the data validation list has been looped through.
If possible, if I was to run the macro again I want it to recognize there is data in column **B** in worksheet Gym Load Monitoring and paste the values in the next blank column, and so on for each time, the macro is run.
I've got the current code written but I have a feeling I am completely off track:

```
Sub PasteLoads()
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long


'Which cell has data validation
Set dvCell = Worksheets("Gym Weekly Template").Range("C8")

'Determine where validation comes from
Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

i = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value

    With Worksheets("Gym Load Monitoring")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Gym Weekly Template").Range("W73").Copy.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End (xlUp)

Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

I'm not very experienced with VBA coding so this is probably wrong. I know I need to add in Offset but not sure where.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Added few additional variables to reduce repetition, and a check to make sure you're writing to an empty column each time you run your Sub.

Untested:

```
Sub PasteLoads()
    Dim shtGWT As Worksheet, shtGLM As Worksheet
    Dim dvCell As Range
    Dim inputRange As Range, resultRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long, nextCol As Long


    Set shtGWT = Worksheets("Gym Weekly Template")
    Set shtGLM = Worksheets("Gym Load Monitoring")

    'Which cell has data validation
    Set dvCell = shtGWT.Range("C8")
    Set resultRange = shtGWT.Range("W73")

    'Determine where validation comes from
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

    nextCol = 2
    'find an empty column
    Do While Application.CountA(shtGLM.Cells(2,nextCol).Resize(500, 1)) > 0
        nextCol = nextCol + 1
    Loop

    i = 2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In inputRange.Cells
        dvCell.Value = c.Value
        shtGLM.Cells(i, nextCol).Value = resultRange.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. Is there any way I would be able to alter it so it disregards to first row in determining data in the columns (as there will be labels placed there)?